# adsdb INSERT INTO

Tags: python, mysql, advantage-database-server

I have an ADT that I can modify using Advantage Data Architect.

However I wish to be able to modify the table using adsdb. I've created the table using;

```
cnxn = adsdb.connect(DataSource='c:/Python27/', ServerType='1')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE Persons (PersonID INTEGER, LastName CHAR(100), FirstName CHAR(100))'
```

I am able to Insert data into the PersonsID field using;

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID) VALUES (01)')
```

However trying to insert data into the the columns of char type using;

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Persons (LastName) VALUES ("Smith")')
```

I get the error;

```
adsdb.OperationalError: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = S0000;   NativeError = 2121;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Column not found: Smith -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 40
```

I have tried using single quotes and no quotes in the VALUE field, but I'm still presented with the error. I have Google'd the error codes provided but I have found little in way of a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ADS SQL (and indeed in ANSI-SQL) strings (CHAR typed) values [have to be enclosed in single quotes](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage12/index.html?master_sql_literals.htm):

```
INSERT INTO Persons (LastName) VALUES ('Smith')
```

[In Python a string literal](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) can either be written in single or double quotes:

```
print("Hello")
print('Hello')
```

Since the correct SQL statement does not contain double quotes it would be easier to use a double quoted string literal:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Persons (LastName) VALUES ('Smith')")
```

If you want to use a single quoted string literal, you have to escape the single quotes inside the literal:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Persons (LastName) VALUES (\'Smith\')')
```

But I wouldn't do it like that, since using string interpolation or string concatenation to get values into an SQL statement [is very dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work?rq=1) and can lead to SQL injection.

The correct way would be using a parameter:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Persons (LastName) VALUES (?)', 'Smith')
```

BTW: "Persons" is a terrible table name (The plural of person is people, you should either use "person" oder "people" as the table name).

Comment: Brilliant answer thank you Jens. Thanks for the tip, the Persons table is just for testing :)